# DoesNotExist at /buy_now_payment_done/ Payment matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, razorpay

i have implemented an E-commerce website with razorpay payment integration and when i am got to checkout page with cart items, all logic work properly but when i am click on Buy Now button and then redirect it to "buynow_checkout.html" after that i am making a payment and payment is also successfull but after that i am getting an error :

DoesNotExist at /buy_now_payment_done/
Payment matching query does not exist.

how to resolve this?

here is my code:
Buy Now button
`<a href="{% url 'buy_now' %}?prod_id={{ product.id }}" id="" class="btn btn-danger shadow px-5 py-2 ms-4">Buy Now</a>`

urls.py

```
path('buy_now/', login_required(views.BuyNow.as_view()), name='buy_now'),
path("buy_now_payment_done/", views.buynow_payment_done, name='buynow_payment_done'),
path('checkout/', login_required(views.checkout.as_view()), name='checkout'),
path("payment_done/", views.payment_done, name='payment_done'),
```

view.py

```
import uuid
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.views import View

from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login,logout
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.db.models import Q
from .forms import *
from .models import *
import razorpay

class checkout(View):
    def get(self,request):
        user = request.user
        add = Customer.objects.filter(user=user)
        cart_items = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
        famount = 0
        for p in cart_items:
            value = p.quantity * p.product.discounted_price
            famount = famount+value
        totalamount = famount + 40
        razorpay_amount = int(totalamount * 100)
        client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzp_test_NqHIxmro5EHkHO", "PVE3M1msR3vfdwEcVlFuMWVX"))
        data = {'amount' : razorpay_amount, 'currency' : 'INR', 'receipt': 'order_rcptid_12', 'payment_capture' : '1'}
        payment_response = client.order.create(data=data)
        print(payment_response)

        # {'id': 'order_N4iaQ69zoA5v5s', 'entity': 'order', 'amount': 8900, 'amount_paid': 0, 'amount_due': 8900, 'currency': 'INR', 'receipt': 'order_rcptid_12', 'offer_id': None, 'status': 'created', 'attempts': 0, 'notes': [], 'created_at': 1700917770}

        order_id = payment_response['id']
        order_status = payment_response['status']
        if order_status == 'created':
            payment = Payment(
            user=user,
            amount=totalamount,
            razorpay_order_id=order_id,
            razorpay_payment_status=order_status,
         )
        payment.save()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            total_item_in_cart = len(Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user))
        return render(request, 'app/checkout.html',locals())


@login_required
def payment_done(request):
    # razorpay
    order_id = request.GET.get('order_id')
    payment_id = request.GET.get('payment_id')
    custid = request.GET.get('custid')
    print(order_id, payment_id, custid)
    user = request.user
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=custid)
    payment = Payment.objects.get(razorpay_order_id=order_id)
    payment.paid = True
    payment.razorpay_payment_id = payment_id
    payment.save()

    cart = Cart.objects.filter(user=user)
    for cart_item in cart:
        order = OrderPlaced(user=user, customer=customer, product=cart_item.product, quantity=cart_item.quantity, payment=payment)
        order.save()
        cart_item.delete()
    messages.success(request, f'Payment Successful , Your Order Has Been Placed.')
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
    return redirect('orders')




class BuyNow(View):
    def get(self, request):
        product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        user = request.user
        address = Customer.objects.filter(user=user)
        # Perform calculations or retrieve additional details if needed
        # For example:
        discounted_price = product.discounted_price
        shipping_amount = 40.00
        total_amount = discounted_price + shipping_amount
        razorpay_amount = int(total_amount * 100)

        client = razorpay.Client(auth=("rzp_test_NqHIxmro5EHkHO", "PVE3M1msR3vfdwEcVlFuMWVX"))
        data = {'amount' : razorpay_amount, 'currency' : 'INR', 'receipt': 'order_rcptid_12', 'payment_capture' : '1'}
        payment_response = client.order.create(data=data)
        print(payment_response)

        order_id = payment_response['id']
        order_status = payment_response['status']
        if order_status == 'created':
            payment = Payment(
            user=user,
            amount=total_amount,
            razorpay_order_id=order_id,
            razorpay_payment_status=order_status,
         )
        payment.save()
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            total_item_in_cart = len(Cart.objects.filter(user=request.user))

        return render(request, 'app/buynow_checkout.html', {
            'product': product,
            'discounted_price': discounted_price,
            'shipping_amount': shipping_amount,
            'total_amount': total_amount,
            'razorpay_amount':razorpay_amount,
            'address':address,
            'total_item_in_cart':total_item_in_cart,
            'payment':payment.id
        })
    
    # return render(request, 'app/buynow.html')




@login_required
def buynow_payment_done(request):
    # razorpay
    order_id = request.GET.get('order_id')
    payment_id = request.GET.get('payment_id')
    custid = request.GET.get('custid')
    print(order_id, payment_id, custid)
    user = request.user
    customer = Customer.objects.get(id=custid)

   
    # payment = get_object_or_404(Payment, razorpay_order_id=order_id)
    payment = Payment.objects.get(razorpay_order_id=order_id)
    payment.paid = True
    payment.razorpay_payment_id = payment_id
    payment.save()

    product_id = request.GET.get('prod_id')
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    
    order = OrderPlaced(user=user, customer=customer, product=product, payment=payment)
    order.save()
    messages.success(request, f'Payment Successful , Your Order Has Been Placed.')
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
    return redirect('orders')
```

checkout.html

```
<div id="razorpay-button-container">
      <button id="rzp-button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning fw-bold">
       Pay with Razorpay
      </button>
</div>

{% block payment-gateway %} 
 {% comment %} razorpay{% endcomment %}
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
  var options = {
      "key": 'rzp_test_NqHIxmro5EHkHO', // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
      "amount": "{{ razorpay_amount }}", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
      "currency": "INR",
      "name": "Tech - Store Ecomm",
      "description": "Test Transaction",
      
      "order_id": "{{order_id}}", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
      "handler": function (response){
        var form = document.getElementById('payment_form')
          window.location.href = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment_done?order_id=${response.razorpay_order_id}&payment_id=${response.razorpay_payment_id}&custid=${form.elements["custid"].value}` 
      },
      "theme": {
          "color": "#1f19e0"
      }
  };
  var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
  rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
          alert(response.error.description);
  });
  document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e){
      rzp1.open();
      e.preventDefault();
  }
</script>
{% endblock payment-gateway %}
```

buynow_checkout.html

```
<div id="razorpay-button-container">
            <button id="rzp-button2" type="submit" class="btn btn-warning fw-bold">
              Pay with Razorpay
            </button>
</div>

{% block payment-gateway %} 
 {% comment %} razorpay{% endcomment %}
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
  var options = {
      "key": 'rzp_test_NqHIxmro5EHkHO', // Enter the Key ID generated from the Dashboard
      "amount": "{{ razorpay_amount }}", // Amount is in currency subunits. Default currency is INR. Hence, 50000 refers to 50000 paise
      "currency": "INR",
      "name": "Tech - Store Ecomm",
      "description": "Test Transaction",
      
      "order_id": "{{order_id}}", //This is a sample Order ID. Pass the `id` obtained in the response of Step 1
      "handler": function (response){
        var form = document.getElementById('buynow_payment_form')
        console.log(response.razorpay_order_id);
          window.location.href = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/buy_now_payment_done?order_id=${response.razorpay_order_id}&payment_id=${response.razorpay_payment_id}&custid=${form.elements["custid"].value}` 
      },
      "theme": {
          "color": "#1f19e0"
      }
  };
  var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
  rzp1.on('payment.failed', function (response){
          alert(response.error.description);
  });
  document.getElementById('rzp-button2').onclick = function(e){
      rzp1.open();
      e.preventDefault();
  }
</script>


{% endblock payment-gateway %}
```

models.py

```
# Create your models here.

class Profile(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    forget_password_token = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    locality = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.IntegerField()
    zipcode = models.IntegerField()
    state = models.CharField(choices=STATE_CHOICES, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Mobile'),
    ('L', 'Laptop'),
    ('TV', 'TV'),
    ('W', 'Watch'),
    ('FG', 'Fridge'),
    ('EP', 'Earphone'),
    ('PR', 'Printer'),
    ('TW', 'Top Wear'),
    ('BW', 'Bottom Wear'),
)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    selling_price = models.FloatField()
    discounted_price = models.FloatField()
    description = models.TextField()
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=12)
    product_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='productimg')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Cart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
    
    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.discounted_price


STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('Accepted', 'Accepted'),
    ('Packed', 'Packed'),
    ('On The Way', 'On The Way'),
    ('Delivered', 'Delivered'),
    ('Cancel', 'Cancel'),

)

# for razorpay payment gateway
class Payment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.FloatField()
    razorpay_order_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    razorpay_payment_status = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    razorpay_payment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)



class OrderPlaced(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='Order Placed')
    payment = models.ForeignKey(Payment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")

    @property
    def total_cost(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.discounted_price
```

Comment: Don't hardcode the url `window.location.href = \`http://127.0.0.1:8000...\``. Instead, use the [url builtin tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)

Answer (score 1):

You are using backtick ` and ${ for javascript template variables but including django context references inside them.  They are different.  Context variables are figured out server side and use {{.  js template variables are figured out client side and use ${

So you probably want to use a pattern like:

```
window.location.href = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/buy_now_payment_done?order_id={{response.razorpay_order_id}}&payment_id={{response.razorpay_payment_id}}&custid={{form.elements["custid"].value}}"
```

Comment: `form.elements.custid.value` instead of `form.elements["custid"].value` ?